# Instantiate JavaFX window

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I would like to have a JavaFX window object in it's own thread that I can instantiate and update from outside (very often, 10-20 per second). This window should view images and be update-able from other classes.

**Main class**

```
ImageViewer window = new ImageViewer("Preview");
window.show();
window.updateFrame(image);
```

**ImageViewer class**

```
public class ImageViewer extends Application{

private StackPane pane;
private ImageView imgView;
private Stage primaryStage;

public ImageViewer() {
}

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    pane = new StackPane();
    imgView = new ImageView();
    pane.getChildren().add(imgView);
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public void updateFrame(Image image) {
    imgView = new ImageView(image);
}

public void show() { Application.launch(); }
```

The constructor unfortunately doesn't take any parameters and nothing happens when I try to set any values in this object. Why is this?

Comment: The `start(...)` method is where your application should start up. The `Application.launch()` method will create an instance of your `Application` subclass for you. If you want classes that you are going to reuse from other parts of your application, they should not be subclasses of `Application`. You probably need to restructure this application.

Comment: Do you mind explaining more? I can't quite grasp the concept of JavaFX. How can I have a window separated (threading wise) from my main application to load images in?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense: like almost all UI toolkits, JavaFX is single threaded and all UI elements must be accessed from the FX Application Thread. I will try to show the structure of how I would write the app that you have described.

Comment: Thanks. That would be great. I am trying now for hours. I can't even redraw an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Application` class represents an entire application, and its `start(...)` method is the method where the application starts (you should really think of the `start(...)` method as the equivalent of the `main(...)` method in a traditional Java application). Your question seems to imply that you think the `Application` class represents a window; the `Stage` class represents a window. However, as far as I can tell, your application only needs a single window anyway.

When you call `Application.launch()` (or in Java 8 just execute the JVM specifying an `Application` subclass as the main class), the FX toolkit creates an instance of your `Application` class itself, starts the FX toolkit and FX Application Thread, and calls the `start(...)` method on the `Application` instance, passing in a `Stage`. You should really never instantiate your `Application` subclass yourself; if you do you will have a different instance from the one whose `start(...)` method was called.

Like almost all UI toolkits, JavaFX is single threaded. All operations on "live" scene graph elements must be executed on the JavaFX Application Thread. You can certainly have background threads, but if they need to update the UI, they should arrange for the updates to happen on the FX Application Thread, either by calling `Platform.runLater(...)` or by leveraging the `javafx.concurrent` API. (The phrase "have a JavaFX Window object in its own thread" doesn't even make sense to me. Threads don't have objects, objects exist on the heap. Threads are just the abstraction of an independent sequence of executable statements.)

So if you want a JavaFX application to have a background thread that periodically updates the image in an image view, you could do something like this:

```
// imports omitted

public class MyImageUpdatingApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label("Main application");
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(label);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        startImageUpdateThread();
    }

    private void startImageUpdateThread() {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(imageView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        Stage imageViewWindow = new Stage()
        imageViewWindow.setScene(scene);
        imageViewWindow.show();
        final int pause = 50 ;
        Thread t = new Thread( () -> {
            while (moreImagesToGet()) {
                Image image = getNextImage() ;
                Platform.runLater( () -> imageView.setImage(image) );
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(pause);
                } catch (Exception exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                    break();
                }
            }
        });
        t.setDaemon(true); // this thread won't prevent application exit
        t.setName("Image update thread");
        t.start();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Obviously, you could factor the code from `startImageUpdateThread` into a separate class if you wanted.

Note that this answer is just to demonstrate the relationship between a thread generating images and the UI. In real life, you'd likely need some more sophisticated code to make this perform adequately; it's unlikely you can generate and display the images fast enough, so you'd probably need a `BlockingQueue<Image>` to act as an image buffer, with one thread generating the images and one consuming them.

Comment: I see more clearly now. Thanks. I have follow up questions though: When you want to use JavaFX, the GUI always becomes your main application and not your actual program? Actually I need multiple windows. I managed to do that by just putting another stage into the `startImageUpdateThread` and instantiating my program class that creates images to get them. Is that how it's supposed to be done?

Comment: That's mostly correct. A `Stage` is a window. To create more windows, just instantiate more `Stage`s. But you should not instantiate your `Application` class. The `Application` is the equivalent of your "main class"; the system just creates the first stage for you and passes it to the `start(...)` method as a matter of convenience. I updated the answer to show creating new windows.